# Facebook with iOS5 and iOS6

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5

I'm about to release an app and it must support both iOS5 and iOS6. But with the new Facebook SDK 3.1 i'm not quite sure on how to integrate the Facebook functionality to work with both iOS versions.

What is the best approach to make both the login and wall posting actions to work in iOS5 and iOS6 version? Are there any best-practices already?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Facebook SDK supports both iOS versions just as well. If you're on iOS6, it will use the built-in authentication, otherwise it'll automatically fallback to the old "fast-app-switching" or Safari model.

So if you [implement the 3.1 SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.0-to-3.1/), you won't have to worry about how the user authenticates:

> The main purpose of the upgrade is to bring compatibility with iOS
>   v6.0 and its native Facebook support. Using v3.1 of the SDK means that
>   your apps benefit greatly from that support when it is available, but
>   that they automatically fall back to use the previous app-switching or
>   web-based authentication flows on older versions of the operating
>   system.

More on implementing support for the built-in Facebook accounts on iOS 6: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/